# Tailwind can't load my custom font in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sass, tailwind-css, laravel-mix, google-fonts

I want to use a custom font, ex. Montserrat, in my app based on Laravel 8 with VueJS3, etc. I tried many solutions which I found on the internet, but none worked. No matter what I do, I still have Nunito, etc., as my default font. Of course, it worked when I added this

```
style="font-family :Monserrat"
```

to HTML but that's not the solution.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
    purge: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/**/*.js',
        './resources/**/*.vue',
    ],

    theme: {
        customForms: theme => ({
            default: {
                radio: {
                    iconColor: theme('colors.yellow.500'),
                },
            },
        }),
    fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Montserrat'],
        serif: ['Montserrat'],
        mono: ['Montserrat'],
        display: ['Montserrat'],
        body: ['Montserrat']
}
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {
            opacity: ['disabled'],
        },
    },
    darkMode: 'media',
    plugins: [
        require('@tailwindcss/custom-forms'),],
};
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');


mix
    .js('resources/js/admin/app.js', 'public/js/admin')
    .js('resources/js/app_mobile.js', 'public/js/')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/').vue()

    .sass('resources/sass/admin/app.scss', 'public/css/admin')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/', {}, [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')])
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
    })
    .version();
```

**app.scss**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import "variables";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";

@import "layout";
```

Comment: What are you actually using in your view to use the font?

Comment: It pretty much works like [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/W9D0REnISq?file=config). Can you show how you implement in your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***problem solved***

The current application code referred to an old compiled app.min.css file that existed and was not removed by mistake.

Meanwhile, Laravel mix & sass was compiling an app.css file that was not used in the application at all.